# Pdf file is not downloading with php using header()

Tags: php, http-headers, codeigniter-3

I want the user to be able to download some files I have on my server, but when I try to download file shows error like below.

[image: error pdf file]

### code

```
 public function saveattachment(){
    $fn=$this->input->get_post('fn');
    $userid=$this->input->get_post('autherid');
    $file_url = realpath("./private").$userid."/".$fn;
    $file_name =basename($file_url);
    $ext = explode(".", $file_name);
    
    switch($ext[sizeof($ext)-1])
    {
        case 'jar': $mime = "application/java-archive"; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = "application/zip"; break;
        case 'jpeg': $mime = "image/jpeg"; break;
        case 'jpg': $mime = "image/jpg"; break;
        case 'jad': $mime = "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor"; break;
        case "gif": $mime = "image/gif"; break;
        case "png": $mime = "image/png"; break;
        case "pdf": $mime = "application/pdf"; break;
        case "txt": $mime = "text/plain"; break;
        default: $mime = "application/force-download";
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));   
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $file_url;
    }
```

The file is downloaded but its not opening.

Comment: echo $file_url? shouldn't you use readfile($file_url);?

Comment: If I use readfile($file_url); then also same error. I have tried.

Comment: Well you can't simply echo the path of the file in order to download it, you'll need to read it. Maybe you should check your error logs for further details.

Answer (score 0):

**header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, 
Sample Code

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called file_name_for_download.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='file_name_for_download.pdf'");

// The PDF source is file_for_read.pdf
readfile("file_for_read.pdf");
?>
```

In your case use basic code and make sure its working fine, then add additional code as per requirements

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo $file_url;` by `readfile($file_url);`

Comment: @Kevin specify what is not working - is there any error in the error log? If so, post it, or analyze first and then post it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had coded as `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));` and i replaced this by `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));`. Now its working. Thanks all for your time to help me.